# Capturing confirm message triggered by setTimeout javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, alert, confirm

I'm making a board game and I have a function that calls various alerts based on the destination of the player. For the final destination, I am trying to call the alert message, then call a confirm message asking if they want to play again. I want to capture the confirm response and trigger a reset() function if they click OK.

For the order of the alert and then confirm, the only way I could think of to stagger them was to make the setTimeout delay a little bit longer for the confirm message than the alert message.

Also, my else statement is a console.log("Game over."), and this is showing up in the console even before the confirm message pops up that is supposed to trigger it. In addition, clicking OK or cancel on the confirm message is not triggering anything. Not sure what's going on.

```
function message(dest) {

if(dest===5) window.setTimeout(alert, 5000, "Great start.");
... (a lot more else if statements here)
else if (dest===134) {
    window.setTimeout(alert, 3000,"You made it.");
    if (window.setTimeout(confirm, 5000, "Game over. Do you want to play again?")==true) reset();
    else console.log("Game over.")
}
```

Comment: This is more a suggestion than an answer, which is why I'm making it a comment. But seems like there is not a good reason for you to have an alert followed by a confirm. Something like a confirm with the message "Great job. You made it! Would you like to play again?" would accomplish the same goal. Also, if you want more control over the popup box, then I would recommend rolling your own alert/confirm box.

Comment: Even if I remove the alert message and just leave the confirm message, the reset function is still not being called. I am wondering where in my syntax there is an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you are looking for something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/Lrwur3ek/

```
function message(dest) {

if(dest===5) 
    window.setTimeout(alert, 5000, "Great start.");

else if (dest===134) {
    window.setTimeout(alert, 3000,"You made it.");
    window.setTimeout(MyConfirm, 5000);


}
}

function MyConfirm(){
    if(confirm("Game over. Do you want to play again?"))
        reset();
    else
        noReset();
}

function reset(){alert('reset');}
function noReset(){alert('no reset');}

message(134);
```

btw I think setTimeout is not the right way to manage your events

Comment: Even in your JSFiddle (and likewise the same issue I'm experiencing), the alert "You made it" comes after the confirm message "Game over. Do you want to play again?". Game over should come secondary. Also, do you have any suggestions for what to use in place of setTimeout?

Comment: The confirm is first in the fiddle because the first argument (the function) to `setTimeout` is being invoked immediately. If `window.setTimeout(MyConfirm(), 5000);` is changed to `window.setTimeout(MyConfirm, 5000);`, it works as expected.